# Laravel jetstream using vite

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, vite, laravel-jetstream

sorry in advance my english is bad

I have a problem when I will use laravel jetstream for my project. Because when i used stack livewire, the display doesn't match, here I give the output result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVdZb.png)

And also I've run npm install & npm run dev so it will run development using mix as default
Here I will give the project folder structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGzij.png)

maybe what I can conclude is to change the development process from mix to vite, or there are hints from the experts here on how to solve the problem?.
Thank you in advance

Comment: UP... I've the exact problem and looking for solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can fix this issue by replacing the @vite with these one in views/layouts/app and guest blade.

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

because you install previous version of laravel, @vite was added in 9.*+ laravel so i think its just bc you using 8.* (any <9) version, just install previous jetstream version for example **composer require laravel/jetstream:2.7.0**

Answer (score 2):

go to **resources\views\layouts\guest.blade.php** and **resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php** and replace below code, if its not there, just insert below code in these two files.
**and also remember to comment out @vite line, see below screenshot.**
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMH1K.png)
I hope it will solve the problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this can help you to solve @vite :
**php artisan view:clear**